# Better solution for dealing with large number of click events with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, anonymous-function

I have a large number of buttons in my page and i want to add a click event to each of the buttons , that is when the user click the buttons it shows the corresponding button value.

i have already implement a method with the help of anonymous functions. i have included my code below

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1"/>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i =0;i<100;i++)
    {
        $("#div1").append("<input type='button' class='myclass' id='mybutton" + i + "' value='mybutton" + i + "'> ");
    };

    $(".myclass").click(function(e){
        alert(e.target.id);
    });
});
```

It is working perfectly, the problem is an anonymous function is created for each button on this Form, that is if i have 10k elements in my page then anonymous function will created 10k times, `i think i causes big memory wastage`. **Is there any better way for achieving this** ? please help me to solve this , any help will be greatly appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Check out jQuery.on()...

Comment: You're worrying (largely) unnecessarily. Your code creates **one** anonymous function and attaches it as a click handler many times.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 how can i overcome that ?

Comment: You miss the point. There's nothing to overcome.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 sorry i can't get you , please correct me if i am wrong, i think my approach will cause a memory wastage am i right ?

Comment: No. **There's only one function**. There is an inefficiency in attaching it, in that `$(".myclass")` must rediscover many input nodes in the DOM. It would be more efficient to define the click handler as a named function before the loop, and make the attachment in the loop.

Comment: Or use delegation as others suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use use event delegation For solving this problem .

event delegation is a mechanism of responding to ui-events via a single common parent rather than each child.

More about event Delegation you can refer **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)** stack overflow question

In you case it is better to use  event delegation

You can use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i =0;i<100;i++)
    {
        $("#div1").append("<input type='button' class='myclass' id='mybutton" + i + "' value='mybutton" + i + "'> ");
    }
    $("#div1").click(function(e){
        if($(e.target).hasClass("myclass"))
           alert(e.target.id);
    });    
});
```

You can check this I have included a example with this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ut766vda/)**

Or You can Adopt Chris's Solutions, it will also works fine

Comment: If efficiency is the issue, then do it like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/ut766vda/1/)**

Comment: @Roamer-1888 superb solution

Comment: @nikeshgupta check Roamer's solution or Chris's

Answer (score 0):

You want jQuery's `on` function, along these lines...

```
$("#containerdiv").on('click', '.myclass', function() {
    alert($(this).id);
});
```

Comment: @nikeshgupta check  Roamer's comment under my post, he had included a fiddle solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 var callback=function(){
            console.log(this.id);   
    } ;
$('#div1').on('click','button.myclass',callback);
    for(var i =0;i<100;i++)
    {
        $("#div1").append("<input type='button' class='myclass' id='mybutton" + i + "' value='mybutton" + i + "'> ");
    };


});      






this is called event delegation.
```

Comment: where did i place your code in my question ?? can you please provide an example